# Execute a php script in the background from Drupal's admin

Tags: php, drupal-8

On my Drupal site, I have a few scripts that I currently execute manually using drush script .... Unfortunately, as it's set up now, I have to ssh into my staging/production environments and run them.

I would like to create an interface in the admin portal that allows admins to trigger off these scripts, only, I would like them to execute in the background. I'd prefer to not have to convert these to cron jobs because 1) some scripts take hours and 2) they don't need to be ran on a regular basis.

I'd simply like the admins to be able to kick off scripts in the background with the click of a button. If a script is running, it should disable the interface's button when the page is loaded.

Could someone point me towards how I could achieve this?

So far, I've created these routes:

```
my_module.scripts.home:
  path: "/admin/config/development/my_module/scripts"
  defaults:
    _title: "Scripts"
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\ScriptsController::home'
  requirements:
    _permission: "administer site configuration"
my_module.scripts.run:
  path: "/admin/config/development/my_module/scripts/run/{script}"
  defaults:
    _title: "Run Script"
'\Drupal\ytp_integrations\Controller\ScriptsController::runScript'
    name: "none"
  requirements:
    _permission: "administer site configuration"
```

And then my Scripts Controller looks like so:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Defines Configurations Controller class.
 * 
 * This class controller i
 */
class ScriptsController extends ControllerBase {

  /** 
   * Home
   */
  function home() {
    $build['table'] = [
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#header' => [
        'Title',
        'Description',
        'Path',
        'Status',
      ],
    ];

    // Retrieve all scripts
    $scripts_config_file = file_get_contents(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/my_module.scripts.yml');
    $script_config = Yaml::parse($scripts_config_file);

    // Create Table Rows and add to table
    $rows = [];
    foreach($script_config as $key => $script) {
      $rows[] = [
        'title' => $script['title'],
        'description' => $script['description'],
        'path' => $script['path'],
        'operations' => [
          'data' => [
            '#type' => 'link',
            '#title' => 'Run',
            '#url' => Url::fromRoute('my_module.scripts.run', ['script' => $key])
          ],
        ],
      ];  
    }
    $build['table']['#rows'] = $rows;

    return [
      '#type' => '#markup',
      '#markup' => render($build),
    ];
  }

  /** 
   * Run Script
   * 
   * 
   */
  function runScript($script) {
    // Retrieve the script
    $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module');
    $script_config = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents("$module_path/my_module.scripts.yml"));
    $script_data = $script_config[$script];

    $script_path = $module_path . '/' . $script_data['path'];

    $execute = exec("drush scr $script_path > /dev/null &");

    \Drupal::logger('ytp')->notice('<pre><code>' . print_r($execute, TRUE) . '</code></pre>');

    return new RedirectResponse(Url::fromRoute('ytp_integrations.scripts.home')->toString());
  }
}
```

Structurally this seems to all work, but when I print out the `execute` variable after running the drush command via `exec`, I get nothing and the code in my script isn't executed.

I changed the command to `pwd` and it printed out the path like expected, but `exec` doesn't seem to know what drush is...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I've updated my question with exactly where I'm stuck and all the code.